# What php files handles routing?

Tags: routing

Given an URL like the following for wordpress

1. http://www.mywordpress.com/2014/10/18/
2. http://www.mywordpress.com

What php files in wordpress is handling the routing?

Answer (score 2):

The [`parse_request` method in the `WP` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src//wp-includes/class-wp.php#L120) parses the URL with the rules generated by the [`WP_Rewrite` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L0). This process converts the request into a set of query variables that the WP class can then use to generate the main query.

Comment: Thanks, but when is the class-wp.php get called? I am interested in what is the first file get called that triggered class-wp.php to handle the path..say calling http://www.mywordpress.com, is it the index.php get call first?

Comment: `index.php` requires `wp-blog-header.php`, which requires `wp-load.php` then calls `wp()` function, which kicks off the process. are you just trying to learn how things work, or is there a more specific goal in this question?

Comment: Thanks! I am interested to learn about how things work, what about http://www.mywordpress.com/2014/10/18/... this one I am quite puzzling and very interested to know what file does it call first that kicks off the process?

Comment: it's the same process for all requests. URLs are matched against rewrite rules, which are patterns that translate parts of the request into query vars, like year, month, day, postname, pagename, taxonomy term, etc.. only the query sent to the database differs for each request, and whatever theme template files go with each type of request according to the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks Milo, but before following template hierarchy, a very first php file should be called by the httpserver right? I am interested to know what it is.

Comment: `index.php`. open that file and follow the includes and you'll see the whole process.